# React Navigation 4x Memory leak

Tags: react-native, memory-leaks, react-navigation

i am new in react native and i think my application has memory leak and i am wondering if anyone can help.I am using redux to store my data and i use a rest api to fetch data from a server.In my scenario i am fetching products categories from a wordpress server.When i select a category i am sending the id and i get the children of this category back and with flatlist i show them to the user.Again and again until the specific category dont have any more children.In this case i bring the products of this category and the user can select a product to buy.At the beginning i dont have any problem but after 7-8 times that i have navigate between categories and screens my application starts to slowing down.I am using push to navigate between screens and not navigate because i want to pass every time different parameter (id).I am thinking that because push re-create the component and push in the stack this is the reason that my application starting to break.I tried to use navigate but i read that if i want to pass every time different parameter that i have to use push.Below is my code.

```
 import React , {useEffect,useCallback,useState} from 'react';
import {FlatList,ActivityIndicator,View,StyleSheet, Text} from 'react-native';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import * as CategoriesActions from '../store/actions/categories';
import CategoryCard from '../components/UI/CategoryCard';



const CategoriesScreen = props =>{
  
   const [isLoading,setIsLoading] = useState(false)
   const [isRefreshing, setIsRefreshing] = useState(false);
   const categories = useSelector(state=>state.categories.productsCategories);
   const loadedCategories =  useSelector(state=>state.categories.categoriesIds);
   let id =  props.navigation.getParam('id');

   
   const dispatch = useDispatch();


   function checkIfCategoryLoaded (id) {
       
       return loadedCategories.includes(id);
   }

  
  
   const loadCategories = useCallback(async () => {

       if(checkIfCategoryLoaded(id)){
           return ;
       }
           setIsRefreshing(true);

     
       try {
         await dispatch(CategoriesActions.fetchCategories(id));
       } catch (err) {
       }
       setIsRefreshing(false);

     }, [dispatch]);
   
    

     useEffect(() => {
       
       setIsLoading(true);
       loadCategories().then(()=>{
         setIsLoading(false); 
       });
     }, [dispatch,loadCategories,setIsLoading]);


     const renderGridItem = (itemData) =>{  
       return ( 
           <CategoryCard
             title ={itemData.item.name}
             image= {itemData.item.image != null ? itemData.item.image.src : null}
             onSelect = {()=>{
                 if(itemData.item.hasChildren){
                  
                   props.navigation.push("Categories",{id:itemData.item.id,name:itemData.item.name})
                 }else{
                   props.navigation.push("Products",{id:itemData.item.id,name:itemData.item.name})
                 }
                 
                 
             }}
          />
       )
     };
     

     if (isLoading) {
       
       return (
         <View style={styles.centered}>
           <ActivityIndicator animating={true} size="large" color="red" />
         </View>
       );
       
     }


   return (
       <FlatList  
          onRefresh={loadCategories}
          refreshing={isRefreshing}
           key={(item)=>item.id.toString()}
           data={categories[id]}
           keyExtractor={(item,index)=>item.id.toString()}
           renderItem = {renderGridItem}
           numColumns={2}
       />

   ) 

}




const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 centered: { flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }
});


export default CategoriesScreen;
```